How to improve quality and descriptiveness of image captioning model captions
I am working on a clothing image captioning model and am creating my own dataset for training. Currently its around 300 images with about 1300 total captions. I know that this dataset is small but during testing the captions that the model outputs are non-descriptive such as "short sleeve shirt" when the majority of training examples would be "black short sleeve graphic shirt" or "black shirt with white hell start world wide text" so why is there such a difference in the output of model and the training examples. I am also unclear how I will be able to get the model to predict the text on a shirt for out of sample predictions.
My model is as such:
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

input1 = Input(shape=(1920,))  
input2 = Input(shape=(max_length,))  

img_features = Dense(256, activation='relu')(input1)  
img_features = Dropout(0.5)(img_features)
img_features_flattened = Flatten()(img_features)
img_features_repeated = RepeatVector(max_length)(img_features_flattened)


sentence_features = Embedding(vocab_size, 256, mask_zero=False)(input2) 
sentence_features = Dropout(0.5)(sentence_features)

attention = MultiHeadAttention(
    num_heads=8,  # Number of attention heads
    key_dim=256    # Dimension of the attention keys
)(query=sentence_features, value=img_features_repeated, key=img_features_repeated)

context = attention  

merged = concatenate([context, sentence_features])

sentence_features = LSTM(256)(merged)
x = Dropout(0.5)(sentence_features)

x = add([x, img_features_flattened]) 
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

output = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(x)

caption_model = Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=output)
caption_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

This is how I am defining the train and validation sets will this cause the model to not be able to predict text on clothing brands that is out of sample?
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(captions)
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
max_length = max(len(caption.split()) for caption in captions)

images = data['image'].unique().tolist()
nimages = len(images)

split_index = round(0.9*nimages)
train_images = images[:split_index]
val_images = images[split_index:]

train = data[data['image'].isin(train_images)]
test = data[data['image'].isin(val_images)]

train.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
test.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)

